# Sweetalert (Ajx - PHP Form) only show success (alert) even when input fields are empty

Tags: php, jquery, forms, email, sweetalert2

I've try so may different ways to make this work, but no luck. Every time I submit the form the success swal alert is the one firing even on empty fields.

**This is my HTML**

```
<!-- Content -->
<div class="content">
    <form role="form" id="form" action="assets/php/mail.php" method="post">

        <div class="row 50%">
            <div class="6u 12u(mobile)">
                <label for="name"></label>
                <input id="name" type="text" name="name" placeholder="Name"/>
                <span></span>
            </div>
            <div class="6u 12u(mobile)">
                <label for="email"></label>
                <input id="email" type="email" name="email" placeholder="Email"/>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row 50%">
            <div class="12u">
                <textarea id="message" name="message" placeholder="Message" rows="7"></textarea>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row">
            <div class="12u">
                <ul class="buttons">
                    <li><input id="submit-button" type="submit" class="special" value="Send" /></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>

    </form>
</div>
```

**This is JS The empty swal I.m using it to clear the form once is submitted is the only way that I got it to work.**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#form').on('submit',function(e) {  //Don't foget to change the id form
$.ajax({
  url:'assets/php/mail.php', //===PHP file name====
  data:$(this).serialize(),
  type:'POST',
  success:function(data){
    console.log(data);
    //Success Message == 'Title', 'Message body', Last one leave as it is
    swal({
      type: 'success',
      title: 'Submmited',
      text: 'Your message has been send!'
    }).then((result) => {
        if (result.value) {
          $("#name").val("");
            $("#email").val("");
            $("#message").val("");
          swal()
         }
      });
  },
  error:function(data){
    //Error Message == 'Title', 'Message body', Last one leave as it is
    swal({
      type: 'error',
      title: 'Oops...',
      text: 'Something went wrong!',
      footer: '<a href>Why do I have this issue?</a>'
    })
  }
});

e.preventDefault(); //This is to Avoid Page Refresh and Fire the Event "Click"

});
});
```

**This is my PHP I use so many different php codes for this but this is the one that actual work best for me.**

```
$name = strip_tags(trim($_POST["name"]));
$name = str_replace(array("\r","\n"),array(" "," "),$name);
$email = filter_var(trim($_POST["email"]), FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);
$message = trim($_POST["message"]);

// Check the data.
if (empty($name) OR empty($message) OR !filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
    header("Location: ../../contact.html");
    exit;
}

$recipient = "php_test@knobcode.com";

// Set the email subject.
$subject = "New contact from $name";

// Build the email content.
$email_content = "Name: $name\n";
$email_content .= "Email: $email\n\n";
$email_content .= "Message:\n$message\n";


$email_headers = "From: $name <$email>";

mail($recipient, $subject, $email_content, $email_headers);

header("Location: ../../contact.html");
```

Comment: Your redirect to contact.html in PHP is the same regardless.  How is the front end supposed to know the fields were empty?

Comment: So I have to redirect to other page?

Comment: No, but you have to have some way to distinguish a success and failure.  How do you expect it to work if you react the same way to both?

Comment: I try to redirect to index and still does the same.

Comment: Pardon my ignorance I'm a total noob at this.

Comment: Sounds like you need to spend some more time learning how these things work rather than copying and pasting code.

Comment: Thanks, I guess I came to to wrong place looking for help

Comment: Right place for help on specific problems, but you'd need a better understanding of what you're doing in order for the help to be value added.   A better place for beginners is school or discussion forums, not a Q&A site.

Comment: You have to check if the inputs are empty or not in the `submit` handler, before the ajax. The `success` calback fires when the ajax resquest is successfull regardless of the data sent. The `error` callback fires when the ajax request cannot be completed... Like because of a wrong URL or something.

Answer (score 0):

Try checking the inputs in the `submit` handler:

```
$('#form').on('submit',function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  if( $(this).find("[name='name']").val()!="" &&  // If the 3 aren't empty, it proceeds.
      $(this).find("[name='email']").val()!="" &&
      $(this).find("[name='message']").text()!=""
  ){
    // The rest of your code here... 

  }else{
    alert("Please fill the form before submitting!");  // Or use a swal...
  }
});
```

About Ajax: The `success` callback fires when the Ajax resquest is successful regardless of the data sent. The `error` callback fires when the Ajax request cannot be completed... Like because of a wrong URL or something.